# How to enter a Git commit message in this editor?

Tags: git, editor

I am trying to enter the Git commit message in the editor which looks like Vi, but none of commands like `:wq`, <kbd>Esc</kbd> etc. are working. Whenever I try to merge the master branch, this window pops up:

```
Merge branch 'master' into awesomebar

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.



--**-Mg: MERGE_MSG                        (fundamental)----All-------------------
```

And the cursor stays right at the beginning of the sentence `Merge branch 'master' into awesomebar`. Neither can I move the cursor, neither can I exit. Typing <kbd>Esc</kbd> gives the following commands:

```
Merge branch 'master' into awesomebar

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.



--**-Mg: MERGE_MSG                        (fundamental)----All-------------------
ESC-
```

And once I type something, I can't even delete it. How do I deal with this?

Comment: You trying to navigate with the keyboard or the mouse?

Comment: keyboard offcourse. but typing arrow keys give **[c** at the beggining

Comment: Try changing your default git editor to vim `git config --global core.editor vim`

Comment: I assume its Vi editor. Can we do something with the vi editor?

Comment: I think you are just neglecting to enter insert mode.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are in in Vi, what does `F1` key? (opening a new tab in your browser can be what it does)

Comment: @Arount ya it is opening a new tab

Comment: I think i am in Vi, but how do i put a merge message thre

Comment: Ok, let's try another approach, while the editor is opened on your commit message, open a new terminal and copy here the result of `ps aux | grep COMMIT_EDITMSG` please

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to be [`Joe`](https://joe-editor.sourceforge.io/)

From what I know to save and exit you must type `^kx` (where `^` is equal to `CTRL`).

If you want to change default Git's editor, just update the `EDITOR` variable, in your `~/.bashrc` by example:

```
export EDITOR="vim"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `(fundamental)` line is a hint that this is some kind of Emacs: *Fundamental mode* is one of the [*Major Modes*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html) of Emacs.

This is the documentation for the basic usage of Emacs:

- [Exiting Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Exiting.html#Exiting)
- [Basic editing commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic.html#Basic)